# How to use Android material components with Support Library compatibility?

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, material-components, material-components-android

I try to use Android Material components library: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android 

For getting material date picker. After I add it to my gradle: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'` and build project, I get error message:

```
    Android resource linking failed
    warn: removing resource 
    .../values.xml:3332: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.
    .../values-v28.xml:15: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
    .../values-v28.xml:19: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
    .../values.xml:6855: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
    .../values.xml:6855: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
    .../values.xml:7134: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
    .../values.xml:7139: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
    .../values.xml:7354: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
    error: failed linking references.
```

As I know there are AndroidX and Support Library conflicts. 
The library documentation states that migration to AndroidX is required.
How can I use this library without migration or maybe someone knows similar material date picker libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can find another material date picker library [here](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker). In order to resolve linking errors you can try following steps:

1) In gradle.properties file add the following code:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2) In app level build.gradle add the following code in `buildTypes`:

```
compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
```

3) set `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to 28.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is inside the documentation.

> If **you don't want to switch** over to the  new androidx and com.google.android.material packages yet, you can use Material Components via the `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` dependency.
>   **Note:** You should not use the `com.android.support` and `com.google.android.material` dependencies in your app at the same time.

You can find another library but keep in mind that other libraries like firebase or google play services today require the androidx migration. Sooner or later it will be the standard.